# TextView shadow not showing up in preview - although working on real device

Tags: android, eclipse

in my android app, I applied a shadow effect to a `TextView` via XML. This is it:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_pinfo_label"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AppName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_pinfo_icon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_pinfo_icon"></TextView>
```

Now, on the device everything works as it should, only the WYSIWYG preview in Eclipse doesn't show the shadow. Is this a general bug or did I miss something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Shadow layers are not supported in the layout editor inside of Eclipse. They will show up correctly on all devices and the emulator even though they do not in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general bug with the android plug-in with eclipse.