# Why isn't shadow appearing?

Tags: android, xml, shadow

The text appears, and the `@color/blue` is fine elsewhere in the code, what else is preventing the shadow from appearing? I have tried values of 1, 10, and 100 for the `shadowDx` & `shadowDy` as well as `shadowRadius`. The shadow does not appear either in the editor (which apparently is expected [TextView shadow not showing up in preview - although working on real device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7827286/708685)) or on my phone, which is my testing device.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shadow_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="i should be shadowed ..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:shadowColor="@color/blue"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text" />
```

Comment: your textview doesnot have a id.. i dont know how it affects shadow.. add a id and see

Comment: oh sorry, that was just left out when i posted the question

Comment: it is stored in `strings.xml` as `#729cd1`. it works for backgrounds and for textcolor, so im assuming it should also work for shadows

Comment: try adding to color.xml then use @color/blue

Answer (score 16):

It only works for me if I use float values. Try this:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shadow_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="i should be shadowed ..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:shadowColor="@color/blue"
        android:shadowRadius="2.0"
        android:shadowDx="1.0"
        android:shadowDy="1.0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text" />
```

And yes, the editor doesn't show the shadow, but it should also show a note that it isn't supported.

Comment: hah, well what do you know, that is it. seems absolutely ridiculous that it can't take ints but oh well. thanks!

Comment: oh hrm ... nevermind. it works but only if my `TextView` has a background color set. otherwise the shadow is invisible/not there