# android shadow layer on TextView not working 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

It looks to me that shadowdx/dy on TextViews isn't working on Lollipop. Adding the following the the style for my text, it works fine pre-L but no shadow on L.

```
    <item name="android:shadowDx">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/product_text_shadow</item>
```

I do realize we have this whole elevation thing now but this shadow api on TextView isn't marked as deprecated.

Comment: Have you tried using floats, e.g. 2.0 instead of 2? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670630/why-isnt-shadow-appearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was `android:shadowRadius` needs to be 1.0 or greater.